# MyClass should only be accessible via the namespace

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to define a class named MyClass inside a namespace MyNamespace. The class constructor should accept a single string argument. It should also have a function named sayHello that returns the string passed into the constructor.

The interesting part is that MyClass should only be accessible via the namespace and should not define any extra global variables. Code should not redefine an existing namespace, but should also function if the namespace is not previously defined.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var MyNamespace = {
  MyClass: (function(string){
    function sayHello(){
      return string;
    }
  })()
    console.log(new MyNamespace.MyClass('Hello!'));
}
```

And the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/wqvc0k1j/8/

p.s.This is not homework, I'm learning JS for my career. 
Thanks!

Comment: That is not valid javascript.

Comment: I don't know, what *are* you doing wrong? What do you expect this to do, and what does it do?

Comment: I've included the description of what needs to be done in the fiddle itself.

Comment: Please post all relevant information **here**, fiddles should only be a bonus to show code in action.

Comment: Yes done! Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class constructor should accept a single string argument.

```
var MyClass = function (str) { };
```

> It should also have a function named `sayHello` that returns the string passed into the constructor.

```
var MyClass = function (str) {
    this._str = str;
};

MyClass.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return this._str;
};
```

> The interesting part is that `MyClass` should only be accessible via the namespace and should not define any extra global variables.

```
MyNamespace.MyClass = function (str) {
    this._str = str;
};

MyNamespace.MyClass.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return this._str;
};
```

> Code should not redefine an existing namespace, but should also function if the namespace is not previously defined.

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.MyClass = function (str) {
    this._str = str;
};

MyNamespace.MyClass.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return this._str;
};
```

Result:

```
var obj = new MyNamespace.MyClass('foo');
console.log(obj.sayHello()); // foo
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Couldn't find anything similar on Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want.

```
var MyNamespace = {
    MyClass: function (string) {
        return function sayHello(){
            return string;
        }
    }
}

console.log(new MyNamespace.MyClass('Hello!')());
```

If you are looking for something like a private member you'd do

```
var MyNamespace = (function(){
    var MyClass = function (string) {
        return function sayHello() {
            return string;
        }
    }

    console.log(new MyClass('Hello!')());
})()
```

Comment: Not quite. MyClass should only be accessible via the namespace

Comment: Added the solution for the other interpretation. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyClass() {
    this.MyAttribute = function(string) {
        return string;
    };
}

console.log(new MyClass().MyAttribute('hello'));
```